# ArraysOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

i can't find what's wrong with this code for the method.it is supposed to generate a 1D double array, with a random number of elements, and of random values between two random integers. i keepgetting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
public class Array1DOperations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=0; int min=0; int max=0;
        generate1D(n,min, max);
    }
    public static double[] generate1D(int n, int min, int max){
        n=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        int x=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        int y=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        min=0;
        max=0;
        if (x>y){
            x=max;
            y=min;
        } else if(y>x){
            y=max;
            x=min;
        } else if(x==y){
            x=min;
            y+=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        }
        double[] a=new double[n];
        for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
            double random=Math.random()*(max-min)+min;
            a[i]=random;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
```

You're looping past the end of the array. The last valid index is `n - 1`, so use `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: thanks it compiled, but now i'm getting 0.0 for all elements.

Comment: @Batoul Your `max` and `min` are zero, try changing it to a range, like `min=0` and `max=100`.

Comment: @Batoul: If you read your code you should be able to see that `min` and `max` are always zero.  And the `x` and `y` variables are never used. What are you even trying to do?

Comment: @Matti @J eventhough i removed min=0, max=0 it still gives 0.0

Comment: @Batoul check your `generate1D` method, you are setting `min` and `max` to zero again.